# What is the LU decomposition of an upper triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

As example let A be upper triangular in form such that the lower entries are zero and the upper entries which lie above the diagonal are nonzero above the diagonal which is also not zero. What is the LU decomposition of such one?

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is upper triangular, then $L=I$ and $U=A$ is a trivial $LU$ decomposition of $A$.

Comment: okay I see my mistake it now makes sense this was the suspicion I held.

Comment: @SocraticaFan Recall that a diagonal matrix can be regarded as both lower and upper triangular matrix.